# Move legend title closer to legend keys

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I have the following plot:

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

p <- 
  qplot(1:10, 1:10, color = letters[1:10]) + 
  theme_grey(base_size = 24)
```

[image]

But I'd like the legend title to be closer to the legend keys. I know I can just white-out the legend and overwrite it using `grid.text`:

```
p <- 
  qplot(1:10, 1:10, color = letters[1:10]) + 
  theme_grey(base_size = 24) + 
  theme(legend.title = element_text(color = "white"))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(p)
grid.text(x = 0.87, y = 0.7, label = "LETTERS")
```

[image]

But this approach has the disadvantage of being inflexible.

I also tried adjusting arguments to `theme(legend.title = element_text(...))` such as `vjust = 1` but that had no effect ([apparently a known issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1502)).

Is there a better/canonical way to modify the legend title position?

Comment: Instead of `element_text(color = "white")` you should use `element_blank()`. The only other way (as long as the bug isn't fixed) would appear to be using `ggplotGrob` and modifying the grob.